# How to implement twitter, email, tumblr with ShareKit

Tags: iphone, sharekit

I want share images to twitter, tumbler & Email with use of ShareKit, but i am not able to do that.
  For twitter uses the code..

```
 SHKItem *item;
 item = [SHKItem image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon2.png"] title:@"Praveen"];
 [SHKTwitter shareItem:item];
```

But i just see a blank screen.  even uses `SHKTwitterConsumerKey`, `SHKTwitterSecret`, `SHKTwitterCallbackUrl`, `SHKTwitterUsername`

but result is blank screen

Answer (score 1):

you must keep the SHKTwitterUsername Empty , and set The SHKTwitterCalBackUrl same value as the value set in the app configuration in twitter side . and don't forget to set to 0 the SHKTwitterUsexauth .